# "which" command not work in shell script with #!/bin/bash but work with #!/bin/zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, which

I have a sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PATH
date
pwd
which nano
```

First three lines work with both #!/bin/bash and #!/bin/zsh but I got a `./script.sh: line 5: which: command not found` with bash, but zsh run the file just fine. Why?

If I enter a bash shell from zsh by typing `bash` and then type `type which` I got:

```
which is aliased to `_which'
```

But if I am in zsh and type `bash -c "type which"`, I got:

```
bash: line 0: type: which: not found
```

Comment: It looks like `which` is not installed but it works in zsh because it's a builtin. However, that does not explain that ``which is aliased to `_which'`` after entering bash shell from zsh.

Comment: Very relevant: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all commands exist as separate executable files: some commands may be *built-in* to the shell you're using.

Apparently you don't have `/usr/bin/which` installed (although some package in your distribution might provide that).

Your `type which` outputs indicate that the `which` command in `bash` is actually an alias, and that alias is only defined when `bash` is invoked as an *interactive* shell. That means it's probably defined in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc`, or in some script sourced from one of those.

When executing `bash` *non-interactively* (as in `bash -c "type which"` for example), then `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` will be skipped, and so the alias won't get defined.

`_which`, in turn, might be a shell function. You could see its definition with `type _which`. Perhaps it is something similar to this:

```
which() { 
   IFS=:
   for x in $PATH; do
      if [ -x "$x/$1" ]; then
         echo "$x/$1"
         return 0
      fi
   done
   echo "$1 not found in \$PATH"
   return 1
}
```

So, if you want maximal portability for your script, it might be a good idea to use a function like that, and so let the script carry its own version of `which` within it.